# If-else statement in Java

Tags: java, if-statement, for-loop, break

I have a slight problem with my program and I'm sure it lies in this loop and if-else statement:

```
for (int i = 0; i < xArray.length; i++)
        {
            if(searchNumber == xArray[i])
            {
                found = true;

                if(found)
                {
                    System.out.println("We have found your number " + searchNumber + " at position " + i + " in the array. " );
                }
                else
                {
                 System.out.println("No match was found.");                 
                }

                break;

            }

        }
```

What happens when I execute the program is that if the searchNumber (which is taken via the Scanner with keyboard input) is found then it will display the appropiate message saying it was found, but if it isn't found no message is displayed. I tried debugging it by talking myself through what every line of code is doing, but when I got to this loop I got very confused.

Comment: you need to display message outside of loop

Comment: What exactly isn't working and what are you confused about?

Comment: You're trying to display "not found" inside the conditional that will only fire if it's found.

Comment: That works if I don't have the i variable in the message, but I want to display in what index of the array the number was found.

Comment: Is searchNumber an array of `String`s?  If that is the case, you need to use the `.equals` method; `==` doesn't work right here.

Comment: @MuseVyze Then save it.

Comment: With this code found always is true  'found = true'

Comment: It's an array of integers, sorry for not mentioning that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure `found` starts as `false`.  Then do the printing after the loop is complete (or broken out of).

```
boolean found = false;
int i;//thanks @DaveNewton !
for (i = 0; i < xArray.length; i++)
{
    if(searchNumber == xArray[i])
    {
        found = true;
        break;
    }
}   

if(found)
    System.out.println("We have found your number " + searchNumber + " at position " + i + " in the array. " );
else
    System.out.println("No match was found.");
```

Comment: @DaveNewton We can't give him full working code. Instead we just educate him, the same way we did for `found` :)

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ Then I'd recommend not using code as an answer, rather a logical explanation.

Comment: I had already tried it this way, but when I tried to initialize the variable i, the loop started giving me an error. It works now though why was it giving me an error before?

Comment: @MuseVyze What was the error?  The issue @DaveNewton mentioned was that of scope.  The `i` was being used outside the `for` loop, so it had to be initialized outside the `for` loop.  Else wise the code cannot reference it

Comment: The error read that the variable i had already been initialized in the main method and it highlighted the for loop, so I'm guessing it's just because of where I initialized it.

Comment: @MuseVyze Try the updated code.  It should work. You may have other points of code where `i` is being used, so this should avoid those errors.

Comment: Oh no I did already try it and it does in fact work I was just curious as to why I was getting that error before. Excuse me for not being more clear.

Answer (score 1):

Dusting off the old Java hat.  This seems more concise?..

```
 int position = xArray.indexOf(searchNumber);

 if (position > -1) {
     System.out.println("We have found your number " + searchNumber + " at position " + position + " in the array. " );
 } else {
     System.out.println("No match was found.");       
 }
```

Just thought - if this is not already an ArrayList, then use:

```
java.util.Arrays.asList(xArray).indexOf(searchNumber)
```

Answer (score 0):

You set the variable `found` to true, then have a test `if (found)`, which will always be true as well. The `else` clause will never execute, because `found` will never be false.

Based on your description it sounds like you need to initialize `found` to false outside the loop. Then if you get a match, set it to true. The if/else statement can then be moved outside the for loop and will behave as you expect it to.

Answer (score 0):

For starters you're prematurely optimizing. Unless your array is obscnely large stopping the check with a break is not necessary. Its good to be efficient, but not at the expense of not working.

When you want to end a loop early I like to use this approach with a while loop instead of a for loop:

```
//init our sentinel flag and our counter
boolean found = false;
int i = 0 ;

//while we have not found anything and we are less than the size of the array
while (!found && i < xArray.length)
    {
        //check our condition
        found = (searchNumber == xArray[i]); 
        i++;          
    }   

//finally react to the terminal state, found or not found and output as needed
if(found)
  {
   System.out.println("We have found your number " + searchNumber + " at position " + i + " in the array. " );
  }
  else
   {
   System.out.println("No match was found.");                 
   }
```

This is functionally equivalent to a for loop with a break as seen in @CyberneticTwerkGuruOrcs answer. Some developers find it easier to read. This also discourages the use of break which can sometimes be hard to determine which statement is being broken out of.

Comment: Also worth noting, you don't actually need the `found` sentinel value you can just check the `searchNumber == xArray[i]`. Again thats a micro-optimization which doesn't really improve the runtime but makes the code harder to read and understand.

Answer (score 0):

Let's analyze the meaning of your code: First, there is a loop scanning through the array. Nothing's wrong with that. In the loop there is an `if-statement` with the condition `searchNumber == xArray[i]` this condition checks if there is a match. If there is one, it sets `found` to true. Then an if-statement checks for `found` and as `found` has been set `true` in the previous line, the code in the statement will *always* be executed, but the code in the `else` will *never* be executed. So that's where the problem is.

So the code to find a number should be like this:

```
for(int i : xArray){ //Foreach loop to simplify 
    if(i == searchNumber){//True if i == number we're searching for
        System.out.println("We have found your number " + searchNumber + " at position " + i + " in the array. " );//Print the message
        found = true; //The number has been found
        break; //cancel the loop as the number is found.
    }
} 
//The array has been searched completely
if(!found){//if the number has not been found
    System.out.println("No match was found.");//Print the message
}
```